# Object reference not set to an instance of an object asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error when trying to save edited information on my form.

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GRCWebApp.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error is related to this line in the controller : currentMembershipType.Type = model.Type;

The Post Method is

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditClubMembershipType(EditMembershipTypeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Go fetch the membership type from the database
            var currentMembershipType = db.MembershipTypes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MembershipTypeId == model.MembershipTypeId);
            // Save new Membership Type  
            currentMembershipType.Type = model.Type;
            currentMembershipType.Description = model.Description;
            currentMembershipType.Cost = model.Cost;
            currentMembershipType.ReducedCost = model.ReducedCost;
            currentMembershipType.DayId = model.ReducedDay;
            currentMembershipType.MonthId = model.ReducedMonth;
            currentMembershipType.MinAge = model.MinAge;
            currentMembershipType.MaxAge = model.MaxAge;
            // Save Changes
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AddClubMembershipType", new { clubId = model.ClubId, editMode = true } );
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
```

The View is:

```
@model GRCWebApp.ViewModels.EditMembershipTypeViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClubId)
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Edit Membership Type</h3>
</div>
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="well bs-component">
                <div class="form-group">
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"    })
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row col-offset-md-1 col-md-11">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "e.g. Full" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"> £</div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4>Do you offer reduced membership cost part way through the year? Add details here:</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row col-offset-md-1 col-md-11">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReducedCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">£</div>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReducedCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReducedCost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReducedDay, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReducedDay, new SelectList(Model.Days, "DayId", "DayNum", 1), new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReducedDay, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReducedMonth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReducedMonth, new SelectList(Model.Months, "MonthId", "MonthName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReducedMonth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4>Are there age restrictions for this Membership Type? Add details here:</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row col-offset-md-1 col-md-11">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinAge, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MinAge, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "1" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinAge, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxAge, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxAge, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "150" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxAge,  "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class=" col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Membership Types", "AddClubMembershipType", new {  clubId = Model.ClubId, editMode = true })
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Do a debug build, get exact error details (Full exception details, including line number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because `MembershipTypeId` on your model is null.  I don't see anywhere in your view where that value is being bound, and if it's not, it will not be part of the submitted form data and therefore not populated in the model passed into the `HttpPost` controller method.

Most common fix is to add a `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MembershipTypeId)` in the form.

P.S. It's really unhelpful to not tell us what line number the error originated from.

Comment: Many thanks thats exactly what it was, sorry t make life hard by forgetting to say where the error was related to.